# why getParentWhileKind in ts-morph not returns the expected parent of child?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, ts-morph

I using  [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph) to analyze my code and I want to get the parent `CallExpression` from `Identifier` location.
So I use `.getParentWhileKind(SyntaxKind.CallExpression)`, but the function returns `null`.

Why? I do have `CallExpression`, which is the parent of `Identifier` (`foo`)

What am I missing? and how to solve it? (other than use `getParent().getParent()..`)

```
import { Identifier, Project, SyntaxKind } from "ts-morph";
console.clear();

const project = new Project();
const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile(
  "test.ts",
  `

  const fn = () => {
    chain.foo.bar('arg');
  }
`
);

const a = sourceFile.getDescendants().find((d) => d.getText() === "foo");

console.log({ a: a?.getParentWhileKind(SyntaxKind.CallExpression) });
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wildflower-ufwvep?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

`getParentWhileKind` works a bit differently than this. From the docs:

> Goes up the parents (ancestors) of the node while the parent is the specified syntax kind. Returns undefined if the initial parent is not the specified syntax kind.

Since the immediate parent of `foo` isn't a call expression, this is just returning undefined. I'd suggest using `getParentWhile` to check each ancestor until you find your first `CallExpression`.

```
const parent = a?.getParentWhile((node) => {
  if (node.isKind(SyntaxKind.CallExpression)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
});
```

It's a bit counterintuitive, because you return `false` when you've found the node you want. But returning `false` basically tells ts-morph that we're done looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template values](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/blob/master/docs/putout-script.md#__a) of [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer, I'm working on.

So if you want to drop `foo` from expression:

```js
chain.foo.bar('arg');
```

to have:

```js
chain.bar('arg');
```

You can use [something like](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/8d6de001d2ff0a4edc5dc917f65e816d/cd8229e0df0b3f847f54e9c91bef940cb548fc06):

```js
// https://git.io/JqcMn

export const report = () => `Drop 'foo'`;

export const replace = () => ({
    '__a.foo.__b(__c)': '__a.__b(__c)',
});
```

You can manipulate with linked values `__a`, `__b` and `__c` in any way you want.